# Revenue Cat: How to manage two different API keys in one Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription, revenuecat

After connecting Revenue Cat with my app on Google Play Store and Apple AppStore I now have two different API keys. One for Google and one for Apple.
But when I want to set the API key inside my Flutter app I have to provide only one single API key like this:

```
  static Future init() async {
    await Purchases.setup('myApiKey');
  }
```

I can't find anything about it in the documentation and I don't know if I have to use one single API key in my Flutter app or if I should simply use a platform check like this:

```
  static const _apiKeyGoogle = 'googleApi';
  static const _apiKeyApple = 'appleApi';

  static Future init() async {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      await Purchases.setup(_apiKeyGoogle);
    } else {
      await Purchases.setup(_apiKeyApple);
    }
  }
```

Does anybody know how to do that? I appreciate every answer.

Comment: You could go with the second option as that is like more maintainable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second option with the variables in a constants file.